# Spring - From xml to Java config

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have web.xml and applicationContext.xml from Spring's project.
I want to change this and get only Java configuration for my project but I can't figure how.

**web-xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring + JAX-WS</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
      </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Register Spring Listener -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
        http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd"
>

    <wss:binding url="/hello">
        <wss:service>
            <ws:service bean="#helloWs"/>
        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>

    <!-- Web service methods -->
    <bean id="helloWs" class="it.capgemini.HelloWorldWS">
      <property name="helloWorldBo" ref="HelloWorldBo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="HelloWorldBo" class="it.capgemini.soap.HelloWorlBoImpl" />

</beans>
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283653/spring-configuration)

Comment: Hope the edit in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851336/spring-utilizing-mongo-implementation-over-jpa/39852442#39852442 helps.

Answer (score 3):

Spring provides a convenient base class for JAX-WS servlet endpoint implementations - `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`. To expose our `HelloService` we extend Spring’s `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` class and implement our business logic here, usually delegating the call to the business layer. We’ll simply use Spring’s `@Autowired` annotation for expressing such dependencies on Spring-managed beans.

```
@WebService(serviceName="hello")
public class HelloServiceEndpoint extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport {
    @Autowired
    private HelloService service;

    @WebMethod
    public void helloWs() {
        service.hello();
    }
}
```

The service itself:

```
public class HelloService {
    public void hello() {
        // impl
    }
}
```

And configuration

```
@Configuration
public class JaxWsConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean wsSpringServlet() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(),    "/api/v10");
    }

    @Bean
    public HelloService helloService() {
        return new HelloService();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment.
So I can use this two classes instead of xml configuration file?

Comment: Yes, also you need add Configuration to your app.

Comment: I can't find WSSpringServlet(), I'm on SpringBoot 1.3.3

Comment: Add following https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.10 depemdency to your project.

Comment: @MikeShauneu what if I can't use WSSpringServlet?

Comment: @LppEdd look at https://github.com/revinate/jaxws-spring/blob/master/jaxws-spring/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSSpringServlet.java, you can make your own implementation.

not sure that I understand your questions...

Comment: @MikeShauneu i couldn't use a GPL library, so I coded one myself. Solved